# Electroplating with iron and copper acetate

Tags: electrolysis

Im trying to do cheep electroplating using iron and copper acetate as in introduction to electroplating and working with acids. Each solution was prepared using heated vinegar and hydrogen peroxide. I notice two things. First, my iron plating happens much slower than the copper plating. Is this because for my copper plating solution i used a vinegar with a 20% acid concentration and for the iron i used a 10%? Voltage is the same at 12V
My next question about about the gas coming off the cathode. Is it hydrogen gas? I was under the impression that my solution would never be depleted. As copper is plated onto an object it is removed from the copper anode and everything just keeps going. But if gas is bubbling up that means something is being consumed and will have be replaced. Is it that on the anode, oxygen is produced which then reacts with the copper and thats why I dont see any oxygen bubbling off?

Comment: Good question, it raises a lot of things which are in an undergrad electrochemistry lecture course. These include things like exchange current density and coordination chemistry from the inorganic lectures.